# Where did the Grimm brothers' story "The Shepherd Boy" originate?

Tags: short-stories, german-language, brothers-grimm

["The Shepherd Boy"](https://archive.org/details/grimmshouseholdt2grim/page/222/mode/2up) is a very short story by the Brothers Grimm which recently found fame in the world of popular sci-fi by being referenced prominently in [an episode of *Doctor Who*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven_Sent_(Doctor_Who)). In general it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimms%27_Fairy_Tales) that the Brothers Grimm didn't *write* the stories themselves but collected them from various traditional sources. But I'm curious if anything is known about the origins of this particular story.

**Is anything known about the history and origins of the story "The Shepherd Boy"?**

Comment: I haven't seen the Dr Who episode, but having read the story now I recognize the diamond mountain from a philosophical discussion in one of the Pratchett novels, though for the life of me I can't think which one. The conversation being along the lines of 'well where's this mountain then?' and protestations about the relative hardness of birds beaks and diamond mountains. I never knew the source of it before.

Comment: Good Omens! That’s where I know it from. https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/62281-i-mean-d-you-know-what-eternity-is-there-s-this-big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the listed attributions in '[The Complete Fairy Tales of the Brothers Grimm All-New Third Edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dec1b-q_of8C&pg=PT1269&lpg=PT1269&dq=%22ludwig%20aurbacher%22%20grimm%20shepherd%20boy&source=bl&ots=yTrNQxfkZ3&sig=ACfU3U0wd7zdJT9IM1i8bw_biFE66b3HmA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIpqDI0srgAhVxSRUIHQFVCH0Q6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ludwig%20aurbacher%22%20grimm%20shepherd%20boy&f=false)' the source was [Ludwig Aurbacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Aurbacher)

> 152. The Little Shepherd Boy “Das Hirtenbüblein” (1819). Source: Ludwig Aurbacher

he seems to have been something of a polymath.

> The work of Aurbacher covers a wide range. From pedagogy, psychology, philology and religion to poetry. He became famous for his Ein Volksbüchlein, a treasure chest of Swabian folk poetry.